# ERROR : OVM-2007 Oracle VM Agent is not active,

Tags: virtualization, oraclevm

I have a server that I installed OVS(OVS Ver. 2.1) on it.

I useing https to connect to the server->

https://localhost:4443/OVS

but I can't create a server pool because this error appear :

**OVM-2007 Oracle VM Agent (IP) is not active**

All needed port is published and IP is pinging from console.
I have to run ovsremaster.py manually.
what cause this error ?
connection has problem ?
access to server is limited ?

.
Thanks.

Comment: I think problem is connection between them
because there is no different if ovs-agent was running or was stopped
this error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

ports that needed to be open are open.

but connection can't use them.

I test, use telnet :

telnet IP PORT

and connection failed was result.

Some port are open in iptables in same command, but just port 22 is respond and other ones are seem that still close.
What Can I do now ?